# Datagrid Row Selection On Button Click In WPF

Tags: wpf, datagrid, row

I am having a Datagrid that gets populated with values from a DataTable. In my program i have four buttons: Goto First, Last, Next and Previous, as the name name indicates i have to select the rows based on the selection made using these buttons. Everything seems well if i use the below code to get the row (for example first row).

```
DataGridRow row =(DataGridRow)userControl.m_DataGrid.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromIndex(0);
row.IsSelected = true;
```

But the code throws null value when there is more rows than the height of the Datagrid(When scrollbar comes into picture).

Please help me out of this issue. I think this is because of the view problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Due to virtualization the containers are only created when the object is in view, so you could first scroll the item into view using the [respective method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datagrid.scrollintoview.aspx), wait for the creation of the container and then select it.

As this is rather messy i would suggest binding the `IsSelected` to a property on your item using a style for `DataGridRow` (set it as [`ItemContainerStyle`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.itemscontrol.itemcontainerstyle.aspx)). Then you can just set the property to true and scroll the item into view if need be.

Comment: I tried the first method(ScrollIntoView), so i am able to move to the first and last position, but Selection of the row is still not possible as it gives null value. Only for First row its behaving in a good manner.

**CustomerGrid.ScrollIntoView(CustomerGrid.Items[0]);
            DataGridRow row = (DataGridRow)CustomerGrid.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromIndex(0);
            row.IsSelected = true;
            row.Focus();**

Comment: @Kris: I said you need to **wait  for the container to be created**, you cannot do this in the same method, the grid will not even have scrolled at that point since that is done by the UI-thread when it is idle. I would not try to do this, it's a royal pain.